# Customizing Shell navigation flyout icon to include a label

Tags: android, ios, shell, xamarin.forms, navigation

I was wondering how to achieve following functionality:

User enters Shell instance. I'd like to override the FlyoutIcon on main pages (the ones accessible through tabbar on the bottom) to mimic back button with custom back chevron + custom text, while preserving the page title.

Problem 1.)
creating a png for that overrides the back button on ALL pages in Shell navigation, so when I go to any page through Shell.Current.GoToAsync, instead of seeing a back button I see the png I casted.

Problem 2.)
when assigning FlyoutIcon property to be the chevron, I can't add the custom text next to it.

Problem 3.)
Custom TitleView does not work very well, because it's hiding the title of the page. Unless I can have it reliably set in the middle I won't be able to use TitleView.

Any help is appreciated.

Attached is a quick snapshot of the navigation bar and short marking of what I want to achieve:
[image: desired outcome/current presentation]

Now, I know this is something that can be stabilized by having the whole app in shell, but that won't be possible at least for a while and deadlines are coming up fast. If one of you smart folks could point me in the direction of the answer or present a solution to me I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you that when setting the Custom TitleView in Shell Page, the title of the page will be hidden by the Custom TitleView.

What I suggest is that we can use binding `{Binding Title}` in a label to set the title anywhere you want.

Below is the code snippet for your reference:

```
 <Shell.TitleView>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Customtext}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#FFFFFF"></Label>
        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Grid.Column="1"  Text="{Binding Title}"  FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="20,0"></Label>
    </Grid>
</Shell.TitleView>
```

Comment: That's getting somewhere - would you mind telling me if I can remove the space that the Chevron is occupying? It's the FlyoutIcon property of the shell page. If I can remove it and stretch that title view, put a styled button there I'd achieve what I need. 

I'm totally ok with custom renderer/native controllers to achieve that, but looking through my searches online didn't yield any successful method so far!

Comment: Thanks for your response,Luke,would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: Of course - could you give me a day to get it set up? Also, is DMing you OK?

Comment: Let's keep in touch in this thread,Thanks!